# Receiving data from calling Firebase Cloud Function in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to calling a firebase cloud function that I have written.

I have tested the function using Postman to mimic HTTP requests. Here is the JSON result when I call my function within Postman:

```
{
 "groups": [
    {
        "isPublic": true,
        "members": [
            true
        ],
        "numberOfMembers": 1,
        "groupId": "-LAOPAzMGzOd9qULPxue"
    },
    {
        "isPublic": true,
        "members": [
            true
        ],
        "numberOfMembers": 1,
        "groupId": "-LAOP7ISDI2JPzAgTYGi"
    }
 ]
}
```

I am attempting to do the same and retrieve this JSON list within my android app. I am following the example on Firebase's website :https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

This is Firebase's example on how to retrieve the data:

```
return mFunctions
        .getHttpsCallable("addMessage")
        .call(data)
        .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
            @Override
            public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                return result;
            }
        });
```

It is unclear how I can take the result from my cloud function and use it in the rest of my Android app.

Furthermore, this example returns a Task object which according to Firebase's documentation has now deprecated : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/Task)

Is there a clearer, more simple way to handle the data from a function call?

Calling a function is extremely simple so I feel that there must be a more straight forward method to receiving the response.

Comment: Task is deprecated in the Admin SDK for Java, which is what you're linking to.  For the Android SDK, Task is still used for all async work, and that's not changing any time soon.

Comment: Did you find a solution? It must be perfect if they provide method like `getValue` or `toObject` which automatically generate model object from retrieved snapshop in RTDB and Firestore. It seems `task.getResult().getData()` returns an `Object`. Does it means it can also be String, Integer, List or something else?

Comment: As an educated guess, if the result string is the string representation of your JSON, you can use Gson to parse the JSON and store the data into a class.

Answer (score 7):

If you're simply interested in getting JSON from your endpoint, do this from your Activity:

```
        mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("getGroups") //Whatever your endpoint is called
            .call()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(HttpsCallableResult httpsCallableResult) {
                    try{
                        Gson g = new Gson();
                        String json = g.toJson(httpsCallableResult.getData());
                        Groups groups = g.fromJson(json,Groups.class);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("Error",e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Given that most deserialisation frameworks in Android don't like taking Maps as input, it would be nice if Firebase Functions could provide raw json, rather than doing this round-trip to generic objects.

Comment: You can get a raw json as well. You are not forced to deserialize it to a certain data class. @joerick

Comment: @Xenolion how? I couldn't find that in the documentation

Comment: @Xenolion I would also like to know how to get the raw value (as a String)?

Comment: `httpsCallableResult.getData().toString()` did not work?? @SvenJacobs

Comment: @Xenolion When the function returns JSON, `getData()` returns a `Map<String, Object>`. Calling `toString()` on a `Map` does not produce a JSON string.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Kotlinx Serialization, you can use [`org.json.JsonElement`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) to convert the result data into a format that the serialization framework will accept:

```
val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable)

fun getPerson(personId: String): Task<Person> {
    val function = functions.getHttpsCallable("getPersonInfo")

    return function.call(mapOf("personId" to personId)).continueWith { task ->
        val result = task.result ?: throw Exception("result is null")

        val jsonString = org.json.JSONObject(result.data as Map<*, *>).toString()
        json.parse(Person.serializer(), jsonString)
    }
}
```

Comment: The snippet "json.parse(Person.serializer(), jsonString)" didn't work. Replace it with "Json.parseToJsonElement(jsonString)"